# Access method from another class in python

Tags: python, class, queue, doubly-linked-list

I have the following code:

```
from DoublyLinkedList import DoublyLinkedList

class LinkedQueue():
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = DoublyLinkedList()

    def enqueue(self, val):
        self.data.add_first(val)

x = LinkedQueue()
x.enqueue(2)
x.enqueue(4)
print(x)
```

where LinkedQueue uses a DoublyLinkedList as a data member. I load up the list with 2 and 4 as values, and I try to print the DLL "x" using the DoublyLinkedList class **repr** method. This returns `<__main__.LinkedQueue object at 0x00BBEC90>` instead of the desired `[2,4]`.

DoublyLinkedList **repr** method below:

```
class DoublyLinkedList:
    def __repr__(self):
        return "[" + ','.join[str(i) for i in self] + "]"
```

Comment: You need to `print(x.data)`

Comment: x is just an object of LinkedQueue. LinkedQueue did not inherit anything, so why should a print call on `x` reach DoublyLinkedList's repr?

Comment: You must provide a `__repr__` method for `LinkedQueue`, too.

Comment: `def __repr__(self): return repr(self.data)` ?

Answer (score 2):

The DLL is `x.data`, not `x`. If you want to call the DLL method, you need to print that:

```
print(x.data)
```

If you want printing a `LinkedQueue` to do this automatically, you need to define a method in that class:

```
class LinkedQueue():
    ...
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.data)
```